# Call Auth.currentSession() At 5 minute intervals in Vuex Store

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm working on an app where I do alot of requests to our API, and sometimes the request end up with expired tokens.

I looked into different solutions like calling Auth.currentsession and setting the header before sending the request, but that doesn't work so well since alot of the libaries we use don't "await" Auth.currentsession to return the new token if the current one is expired.

It seems the best solution is to manually call Auth.currentsession at 9 minute intervals and store the token in the vuex store, Is this possible to be done in the Vuex store.js?

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'


export default createStore({
  state: {
    session: null
  },
  getters: {

  },
  mutations: {
    setSession(state, value){
      state.session = value
    }
  },
  // This function will automatically refresh the token every 9 minutes.
  actions: {
    async refreshSession({ commit }){
      try {
        const session = await Auth.currentSession()
        commit('setSession', session)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }

  },
  modules: {

  }
})
```

I want this to run automatically every 9 minutes without me having to call anything from my other components.

Comment: that's what `setInterval` is good for - by the way, your mutation is called `setSessions` but you `commit('setSession'`

Comment: Oh yeah thanks for pointing out, I wrote this real quick just for the purpose of the question,

Comment: so I can have a function call itself over and over in the vuex store using setInterval?

Comment: if you want the function to call itself, use setTimeout not setInterval

Comment: I do things a little differently though ... for each API call that needs the `session` I check if the session is *about* to expire ... if it will expire, I await the API call that "refreshes" the session, then use the newly acquired session for the API call.

Comment: I posted a solution to what I figured out from your comments, can you review that please? Thanks again.

Comment: I wouldn't post a solution if it needed a review!! It either works (with your code) or doesn't. I'd post an answer using the way I do things, except a) I use pinia not vuex, and b) I don't use any AWS stuff, so have no idea of the flow required and c) I can't even guess what your API calls look like

Comment: I tried that approach initially since calling Auth.currentsession() automatically checks if the token is expired and refreshes it by making an API call to Cognito, problem is that a lot of libraries don't await Auth.currentsession to return, and we would need to modify the libraries code itself which is not something I wanted to do

Comment: Alright I'll test this solution manually now and see if it actually does the job, sorry about that

Comment: All good though - so, you're saying `Auth.currentsession` only actually makes a request when the token has expired? because, that's kind of what I was describing ... I have a function `getToken` that I call on every API request (to get the token) and the token it returns can be the current one or a new one if required - so, all my API calls don't need to bother with the details :p

Comment: Yeah Auth.currentsession does that automatically, It checks if its expired and if not returns the cached response. Issues only happen when the token is expired and it needs to make an API call to get the new one, our other libraries don't wait for it and we keep getting errors, and modifying each library to await it is obviously not a good solution. Anyway your solution worked! The function is getting called every 9 minutes like I expected it to :)

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to create an action in the store.js file that calls Auth.currentsession, and in the App.vue file dispatch the refreshSession event every 9 minutes.

store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'


export default createStore({
  state: {
    session: null
  },
  getters: {

  },
  mutations: {
    setSession(state, value){
      state.session = value
    }
  },

  actions: {
    async refreshSession({ commit }){
      const session = await Auth.currentSession()
      commit('setSession', session)
    }
  },
  modules: {

  }
})
```

App.vue

```
  created(){
      this.sessionInterval = setInterval(() => {
        this.$store.dispatch('refreshSession');
      }, 540000);
  },
```